# How to get the list of available sql server instance(in LAN) and edition(like "Enterprise Edition (64-bit)") name using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get the list of available sql server instance(in LAN) and edition (like "Enterprise Edition (64-bit)") name using C#. I got info such as "Server Name", "Version" using the `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` class. But not able to get the "Edition" of the instance.

Comment: Can you provide us the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think can get edition information with that method as per here:

[MSDN SqlDataSourceEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is the Tsql to get the information.  You could loop through the instances above and execute this:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') As SQLVersionNumber, 
  SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') As ServicePackLevel, 
  SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') As EditionInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to obtain a connection to the SQL Server and query its version using any of the techniques listed here;

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/